# App icon has strange white edges in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes-store, itunesartwork, itunes-app

Have uploaded an iPhone app to iTunes Connect, providing a 512x512 icon with square corners, plus 'Icon already includes gloss effects' key set to 'YES' in my info.plist as I don't want a gloss.

When viewing the result in iTunes Connect, the icon looks fine on the 'App Detail' page where you can view and edit metadata; rounded edges have been applied correctly, with no gloss.

However, on the 'App Summary' page, the icon looks like this:

[image: app icon with weird corners]

As you can see something funny is going on with those bottom two corners.

Has anyone else had this problem? Will the final icon look like this in the app store? If so, how can I fix?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iTunes Connect sometimes freaks out and exhibits strange behaviors like this when they're updating things. IIRC, there has been some maintenance recently over there, so it might be related. If you've sent your image as a regular 512x512, plain image (without rounded corners), it'll be shown correctly on the App Store.

Comment: App now live and all seems fine. Corners still look weird in iTunes connect, but are fine in front-facing pages.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to round corners in your 512x512 icon (as well as in the rest of the icons in your app binary).
The rounding will be done by iTunes Connect as well as by the iPhone Homescreen.

If you do the corner-rounding by yourself, you might end up in having a different radius (that is what you have right now).

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my original question. I haven't rounded the corners, the original image file is square, which is why I'm surprised by the result shown above.